# Confusing word order and cases in a line from the Spiegel

Tags: grammatical-case, word-order

> **Den** Saal, **in dem** Wladimir Putin und Alexis Tsipras in Moskau vor die Presse traten, schmückten für die TV-Kameras drei Fahnen **den Hintergrund**: Russlands Trikolore, Griechenlands blau-weiße Fahne und zwischen beiden – etwas eingeklemmt – die Fahne der EU. – DER SPIEGEL

1. By which means is "den Saal" in accusative?
2. Is "drei Fahnen" a subject of "schmückten"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful German world of free word order and inserted relative clauses! So perfect that not even Germans do it right all the time (even if they're in the Spiegel).

> in dem Wladimir Putin und Alexis Tsipras in Moskau vor die Presse traten

is a relative clause which can be turned into a main clause to read

> Wladimir Putin und Alexis Tsipras traten in Moskau *in dem Saal* vor die Presse

and can further be ignored in the discussion. If we leave it out, we get:

> Den Saal schmückten für die TV-Kameras drei Fahnen den Hintergrund.

and then we realise something is wrong. The standard word order would be

> Drei Fahnen schmückten den Saal für die TV-Kameras.

or

> Drei Fahnen schmückten den Hintergrund für die TV-Kameras.

If you want to put both together, it has to include a genitive:

> Drei Fahnen schmückten den Hintergrund des Saales für die TV-Kameras.

So a correct sentence would have been one of the following:

> Den Saal schmückten für die TV-Kameras drei Fahnen.
>   Den Hintergrund des Saales schmückten für die TV-Kameras drei Fahnen.
>   Den Saal schmückten für die TV-Kameras drei Fahnen **im** Hintergrund.

Although I don't like the last option.

So *drei Fahnen* is the subject of the sentence because they decorate *den Saal* (accusative).

Comment: +1, @Jan native german?

Comment: @TopQuestions: Yes, Sir!

Comment: Alles klar, da hätte ich mal ein bisschen besser in der Schule aufpassen sollen...

Comment: Spiegel is not a benchmark for good German. Neither are many other newspapers and magazines.

Comment: @MartinPeters Are there any newspapers that are?

Comment: @Jan Good question! For newspapers you might try "Der Freitag" www.freitag.de , for magazines, if you are interested in literature, "Akzente" http://www.goethe.de/wis/med/prj/dzz/lit/akz/deindex.htm .